# how to overwrite a row in a csv file, or delete it

Tags: python, csv, row

I need to overwrite a random row of a csv file, with a row from another csv file in Python.
It will be ok even if the random row is deleted, and the new row is written at the end of the csv file.
My code is:

```
with open("cache.csv", "r+") as cache_csv:
          writer = csv.writer(cache_csv)
          leggi = csv.reader(cache_csv)
          leggi_list = list(leggi)[1:]
          with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/size.csv') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
```

Then

```
 for row in reader: 
    if self.cache_max-self.observation < int(row[1]):
       for compare_row in leggi_list:
               if compare_row[0] != row[0]:
#add code here that I need
```

I tried with:

```
if compare_row[0] != row[0]:
        riga = random.choice(leggi_list)
        writer.writerow(row, riga)
```

so, take one random row and 'overwrite' it with row, but it's wrong.

I don't know how to do that.
Can someone help me ?
Thank you .

Comment: How do you identify those specific rows in each of the mentioned files? By a line number, or something else?

Comment: I used ` for row in reader:  `  to flow each row in first file and analog in the second one, changing just the names. Then the sintax ` row[0] ` to compare elements of the first column between files. In general, these files consist of two columns, one 'id' (alphanumeric) and the other 'size'. Is that all you need?

Comment: No no no, look, you said you want to overwrite *a random row* of a csv file. I can definitely do that for you, but I doubt that's actually what you're trying to do. I suspect that, by *random*, you actually mean *a specific one, but its specificity is not important to you*. If that's the case, I say no, it actually is important how you identify the row.

Comment: Also, If you have some code, it will be much easier for us if you posted it, including comments at places where you're stuck (related to the question ofc).

Comment: I made some edit at the question, hoping that is better now.

Comment: You can't overwrite a row, unless it is the exact same byte length as the row being replaced; otherwise, you have to rewrite the entire file at least from the point the row changes.  Ideally, read the whole file into a list, change the row, and write the whole file back out.